# How to remove header auto-submitted: auto-generated in exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-server, email-headers, zendesk

I want to forward email from my support adresse support@mydomain.com to my Zendesk address mydomain@zendesk.com in a way that preserves the original sender, AND without exchange adding the header auto-submitted: auto-generated to all emails.

Zendesk suggests this is trivia, and my email provider says this is next to impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to word your request different to your hosting provider instead of asking them to forward the Message (which they probably think implies some type of explicit forward) you can simply add mydomain@zendesk.com as a recipient of the messages received by support@mydomain.com. This can be done easily by either

Using a Transport Rule to Add a recipient https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998315(v=exchg.160).aspx (Use the Blind Copy To Action)

Add mydomain@zendesk.com as an alternate recipient for support@mydomain.com https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.160).aspx

Either should be doable for the hosting provider although they may favour the later.

Comment: Yes you are quite right Glen, this is a working solution - thank you very much. Using the cmdlet "Set-Mailbox -Identity "My Mailbox" -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress mydomain@zendesk.com" was all it took.